# Single switch statement for multiple variables

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C and currently in college. I got a task to make a simple alphabet decoder. I need to input 10 numbers in between 1 and 26, each number representing a letter of the alphabet. So 1 is A, 2 is B,... Z is 26.

```
    int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10;
    
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4, &c5, &c6, &c7, &c8, &c9, &c10);
```

I wrote this for the input, and now I was thinking of making a switch statement for each number, but it seems inpractical to have 10 switch statements. Is there any way for me to somehow make a switch statement that repeats for each input number in consecutive order?

Comment: Use an array to map numbers 1-26 (subtract 1 for array index) to letters A-Z. You definitely do not want to use a lengthy switch here (unless that is explicitly the requirement).

Comment: Are you allowed to use an array?

Comment: @jarmod  I was thinking of making an array, but it is required to do it with a switch.

Comment: If you want to use a switch statement to implement the encoding, that does not mean you need 10 switch statements to encode 10 characters!

Comment: Are you allowed to put the switch statement in a separate "encode" function?  That way you can call it separately for each character you need to encode.

Comment: @Buc Fair warning: For better or worse, downvoting is how Stack Overflow handles "bad" questions. Nothing you can do about it.  It doesn't necessarily mean you're a bad person for asking, so don't take it personally.

Comment: @SteveSummit we are not allowed to use functions. If and switch statements are allowed, as well as for and while/do while loops. Also thanks for the clarification, I don't yet know how things work around here.

Comment: That being said, I think this is a super-valid question, if basic, so I wouldn't worry. (Already it's been edited out.)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused ... you're supposed to input 10 numbers and print their letter equivalents, and you have to use a `switch` statement? The target/requirements keep moving in the comments also .. "not allowed to use functions", `if`, `switch`, and loops are allowed. The answer you accepted is forcing a `switch` statement, no one would ever write code like that. Can you please edit your question and add the assignment in its entirety?

Comment: There are many encodings that use 10 numbers, exactly how are are you encoding it?

Comment: @yano The assignment itself was very poorly worded, so I had some trouble translating it since it's not originally in English. I just contacted the professor and he approved arrays, so I did it with a for loop that goes through the array of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ASCII encoding, you can convert an integer in the range `1` to `26` to a letter from `'A'` to `'Z'` this way:

```
char a1 = 'A' + (c1 - 1);
```

You can then print the letter with

```
putchar(a1);
```

or store it into an array along with the other ones.

If you are required to use a `switch` statement, you can abuse the rule this way:

```
int int2char(int c) {
    if (c >= 1 && c <= 26)
        switch (c) { default: return 'A' + (c - 1); }
    else
        return '?';
}
```

Or this way (less likely to cause a warning):

```
int int2char(int c) {
    switch (c >= 1 && c <= 26) {
      case 1: return 'A' + (c - 1);
      default: return '?';
    }
}
```

Comment: `switch (c >= 1 && c <= 26)` --> [Most ingenious. The old `switch` as an `if` ploy. I really must congratulate you; if there's one thing I enjoy, it's a good `switch` as an `if` ploy.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Pink_Panther_Strikes_Again).

Comment: This might suffice if a machine grades the assignment and it simply needs to find the keyword `switch` in the source code (and get the right output for given inputs). I'd be surprised if this would pass muster with the professor, however (assuming `switch` is indeed an absolute requirement).

Comment: @jarmod: If I were the professor, I would award a badge *best abuse of the rules*, in reference to the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/), but I am sure more abusive solutions can be found :)